# When do we use LQR controller and LQG controller?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, vibrations

I have to conceive a controller to my mechanical system to delete the problem of vibrations, but I don't know when we use [LQR controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-quadratic_regulator) and [LQG controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-quadratic-Gaussian_control).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Linear Quadratic Regulator (LQR) and Linear Quadratic Gaussian (LQG) control are typically used in [Optimal Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_control) methodology where the basis of the control action comes from minimizing a cost function. The LQG approach typically involves modeling your system in state space, designing an observer to estimate the system states, and figuring out a gain vector/matrix that multiplies the observed state vector to obtain control.

So if for example you want to isolate vibrations in your mechanical system using the minimal amount of control energy, then LQG might be the approach you would want to use.

LQR and LQG are often used in Aerospace applications where it's important to minimize energy due to battery or solar panel energy limitations.

Answer (score 0):

The LQR and LQG control are distinct algorithms due to the problems they address. LQR control is used for optimal control of linear systems using quadratic state and control costs, while LQG control is used for optimal control of linear systems with additive Gaussian noise using quadratic state and control costs. As such, LQG controllers can be used for systems which explicitly model measurement noise in the output, while LQR control cannot.